# Pop up removed completly from DOM

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have created the below function that uses `bootstrapalert` where a pop up comes up that holds random data from a database table. But after I trigger the event and close the window I need to refresh the page in order for it to work again. I don't seem to find the issue in the code that causes this problem. Any suggestions for improvement?

```
<script>
  var alertList = document.querySelectorAll(".alert");
  alertList.forEach(function (alert) {
    new bootstrap.Alert(alert);
  });

  function randomName() {
    if (
      document.getElementById("randomNamePopUp").dataset.showned == "false"
    ) {
      document.getElementById("randomNamePopUp").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("randomNamePopUp").dataset.showned = "true";
    } else {
      //window.location.href=window.location.href+"?showRandom=true";
    }
  }

  const urlParams1 = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const myParam = urlParams1.get("showRandom");

  if (myParam == "true") {
    randomName();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don’t see how we are supposed to reproduce your problem, with just this snippet. Also, you should give us a _proper_ explanation of what it means when you say the page was “not working” until you refresh.

Comment: I used snipper because i pasted the copy and i was not allowed to post it. What i mean by refresh is i press the button the alert is displayed i close the alert window and when i press the button again the alert is not working is keep getting removed completely from the DOM. And when i refresh the site i am again able to press the button and view the pop up alert

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (Don't use snippets just for formatting. If clicking Run code snippet doesn't demonstrate the problem, use a code block instead.)